# How to use the SWT List?

Tags: java, arraylist, swt

```
private ArrayList<PrinterProfile> printersList = null;
private ArrayList<PrinterProfile> printers = null;    

...

void Method() {
    ...
    printers = (ArrayList<PrinterProfile>) listOp.getPrinters();
    printersList.setListData(printers.toArray(new PrinterProfile[0]));
}
```

`setListData` is only for `JList` but I am using SWT and `ArrayList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are searching for is the SWT [`List`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/List.html). You can use it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.List;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class MiniExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        // Fill your ArrayList with its content
        ArrayList<String> printer = new ArrayList<String>();
        printer.add("Epson");
        printer.add("Canon");
        printer.add("HP");

        final List printerList = new List(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER);

        // Fill the ArrayList into the SWT List
        for(String print : printer)
            printerList.add(print);

        // Print selection
        printerList.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
                if(printerList.getSelectionCount() > 0)
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(printerList.getSelection()));
            }
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
    }
}
```

Since you already used JFace Viewers in your previous questions, I would suggest using a [`ListViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ListViewer.html) here as well.

**Note**:

Since you are already familiar with `TableViewer`, why not use one with only one column and `setHeaderVisible(false)` and `SWT.MULTI` as style? It would basically have the same effect.